# How to write a query

Tags: sql

I have a table as below;

Id is primary key

```
+----+---------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| Id |  BaseQuestionId    | ColumnContent| Active Flag  |  DependentId | 
+----+--------------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|  1 | 0                  | Ques One     |       Y      |       0      |
|  2 | 0                  | Ques Two     |       Y      |       0      |
|  3 | 0                  | Ques Three   |       N      |       0      |
|  4 | 1                  | Ques One1    |       Y      |       1      |
|  5 | 1                  | Ques One2    |       Y      |       1      |
|  6 | 1                  | Ques One4    |       Y      |       1      |
|  7 | 2                  | Ques One5    |       Y      |       1      |
|  8 | 2                  | Ques One6    |       Y      |       1      |
|  9 | 3                  | Ques One7    |       Y      |       1      |
| 10 | 1                  | Ques One8    |       N      |       1      |
| 11 | 3                  | Ques One9    |       N      |       1      |
| 12 | 3                  | Ques One10   |       Y      |       1      |
+----+--------------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

I need take the count of active questions( where Active Flag='A').

By considering the coulmn DependentId (0-base question,1-dependent question):

TotalBaseQues=3 where ('2' active and '1' inactive)
TotalDependentQues=9   where ('7' active and '2' inactive)

Eventhough the base question is inactive ,I need to list the base question by considering its active dependent questions

**I need the result as below:
 TotalActiveBaseQuestion=3**

Please help me out.

I need to write a query to get my output.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp

Comment: Is your question: Show the count of base questions where Active Flag = 'Y', but include inactive questions if any of their dependants are active?

Comment: Please change the title of the question to something more meaningful and provide details on what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming only nesting questions one deep:

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM tbl a
WHERE DependentId = 0
AND (
    a.[Active Flag] = 'Y'
        OR EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM tbl b 
        WHERE b.BaseQuestionID = a.ID 
       AND b.[Active Flag] = 'Y' 
    )
)
```

If nesting deeper need to use iteration and loops which depends on what database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl WHERE DependentId = 0 AND [Active Flag] = 'Y'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
 SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT A.Id)
   FROM tbl AS A
        LEFT JOIN tbl AS B ON B.BaseQuestionId = A.Id AND B.DependantId = 1
  WHERE B.Id IS NOT NULL
    AND (A.[Active Flag] = 'Y' OR B.[Active Flag] = 'Y')
```

See my [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/75351/12/0) for example.